# Should I directly merge develop branch to production branch?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have 3 branches in my git project:

- develop: This is where I am working;
- semi-production: I am merging develop to this branch in order to automatically deploy my files to a test server;
- production: I am merging on this branch in order to automatically deploy my files to the production server.

My question is:

Should I merge develop branch to production branch, or should I merge semi-production branch to production branch?

The result is the same, but I want to know what is the best practice

Thanks.

Comment: So, having the semi-production branch has some purpose, in your case, right? you test the functionality and, if it presses, probably you merge it with production then. Why you may want to avoid this step? I'm struggling to understand what makes you ask this question, if you're aware of purpose of the middle layer branch. It would definitely not be the good idea to omit testing, unless there is some really urgent hotfix. If you want to redesign your branching strategy, because you don't like the current one, that is a different question. You have a test server, you don't like it anymore?

Comment: One assumes that "semi-production" might sometimes not have newer changes that "develop" does, in which case it is not the case that "The result is the same" when merging from either, because you might have newer stuff in "develop" that should not reach "production". You should edit to clarify why you think it'd be the same, in which case indeed, why have that middle branch at all?

Comment: Why was this closed? It has all details it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [gitflow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), you are using an incorrect nomenclature: your development branch is called a *feature branch*. Your semi-production branch is an integration branch, historically named *develop*. Your production branch is Ok, we'll call it a *master* branch.

According to the original gitflow model, the best practice would be to merge from *develop* to *master*. Reason being you might be merging more than one feature branch into *develop*.

Indeed, if you use *semi-production* to test out multiple features at once, and you have to make hotfixes on *semi-production*, than the result of merging is no longer the same. Let's say that merging from semi-production removes a lot of overhead from you: you tested that code, you send that code into production.

This further breaks down depending on how many devs are there: do you work alone? If more than you are working on the same test server, then they'll too are pushing. Do you thoroughly check you are the only one pushing to the server, and then that the content of the server with tests passing is identical to the content of your development branch, and only if all of these are passing you are opening a merge request to the production branch?

Finally, you might make the merge request from the semi-production to production automatically created if all tests are passed. A human shall review it, but the request is opened in advance reducing time-to-production.